# YouTube API onYouTubePlayerReady not firing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube-api, swfobject

On my site, I am trying to make one youtube video player with multiple links under it to load different videos when clicked. So far it works in IE and Firefox, but I can't get it to work in Chrome. I don't get any JS errors, but by testing with alerts I found that `onYouTubePlayerReady` is not firing. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2/swfobject.js"></script>
            <a name="ytplayer"></a>
            <div id="ytplayer_div">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              swfobject.embedSWF(
                'http://www.youtube.com/v/vlArwl2EoDc&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&fs=1&hd=1',
                'ytplayer_div',
                '720',
                '400',
                '11',
                null,
                null,
                {
                  allowScriptAccess: 'always',
                  allowFullScreen: 'true'
                },
                {
                  id: 'ytplayer_object'
                }
              );
                              var myytplayer;
                              function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
                    myytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer_object");
                  }

              function ytplayer_loadvideo( id ) {
                if (myytplayer) {
                                  myytplayer.loadVideoById(id);
                                }
              }
            </script>
            <div>
            <a href="#ytplayer" onClick="ytplayer_loadvideo( 'vlArwl2EoDc' );"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/vlArwl2EoDc/default.jpg" /></a> <a href="#ytplayer" onClick="ytplayer_loadvideo( 'G4EIgIEngKY' );"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/G4EIgIEngKY/default.jpg" /></a> <a href="#ytplayer" onClick="ytplayer_loadvideo( 'wxXnf_oCRI4' );"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/wxXnf_oCRI4/default.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in this page:

http://losmejoresavances.appspot.com/index2.html

.. and from Chrome works perfect

I used the console to detect the call to the function onYouTubePlayerReady

Comment: Huh.. Ok, well I cleared my cookies and site data just in case, but I don't see any improvement, so here is the link to the page: [http://teamskyfire.elementfx.com/blog/stasis/videos/] I am using a WordPress blog with this as a "page" in the blog, I plan on cleaning the code up quite a bit once things are working.